# Docker: Zip files but exclude certain folders

Tags: linux, docker, aws-lambda

The following is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.7
COPY lambda_function.py .

RUN python3 -m venv venv
RUN . venv/bin/activate

RUN pip install pystan==2.18
RUN pip install fbprophet

# Create zip
RUN pushd /var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
# Exclude folders in .lambdaignore
RUN zip -r -9 -q /var/task/lambda.zip *
RUN popd
RUN zip -9r lambda.zip lambda_function.py
```

You can see one comment where I wrote:

> Exclude folders in .lambdaignore

That's the point where I am stuck. Before building the .zip file. I want to exclude the following two folders:

```
/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/src
/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib
```

Ideally, I just add a .lambdaignore file and each line is just excluded from the .zip That way it would be more flexible. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Does the `zip` compress command have an option to ignore files?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to add --exclude or -x

Comment: I am confused about what the issue is, then. You want to create a zip file without certain folders, and you know what switches to use - what is the problem you are having?

Comment: My problem is that I want to define these folders in a file called `.lambdaignore` That part I didn't manage yet.

Comment: Right. So does the zip command have something to ignore files based on a file of ignore expressions? If not I guess you will have to use some shell trickery to read the lines in the file and build `-x` statements out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` can help you out

Try something like this:

`RUN cat .lambdaignore | xargs zip -r -9 -q /var/task/lambda.zip * -x`